# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error,cant find second model in view

Tags: php, yii2

I have that error in yii2.

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

My view cant see my second model what I put with render function;

in my view I use that model like

```
<?= $form->field($images, 'imagesFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*','id'=>'gallery-photo-add'])->label(false) ?>
```

and put that model in controller index action:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Form();
        $images = new Images();
        return $this->render('form',array(
           'model' => $model,'images' => $images
        ));

    }
```

But in my view I have hint from PHPStorm:
Undefined variable 'images'
and I have that foreach where error was caused

```
public function upload($model){
        $model->imagesFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'imagesFiles');
        foreach($model->imagesFiles as $file){
            $folder = ('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
            $model->image_1.=$folder . ';';
        }
        return $model->save(false);
    }
```

Comment: your code  is not enough .. is not clear where you call the upload($model)  function  and then what's the real content of this $model

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm will see your variable only if you describe it in view file like:

```
<?php

use foo\Images;

/* @var Images $images */

// $images is defined for PhpStorm
```

foreach() needs object or array as param, just put

```
var_dump($images)
```

before foreach call to check variable type.